# Creating Document with SharePoint 2010 Workflow: can I create xml file

Tags: workflow, document, designer-workflow, xml

So I found [this resource](http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/creating-documents-with-sharepoint-designer-2010-workflows) on how to use SPD Workflow to create a new item (or document) in SharePoint 2010. This is exactly what I need because I can fill a field (column in a list) with the string value and throw it into the document after it's created based on condition.

But now I am trying to take this one step further and instead of creating MS Word document I am wondering is there a way to create an xml file like this instead? I know how to create and append to the string held in the field to build the xml, and I know using the method from the link to get that value into the document, but I don't want to have users converting the thing when they download it if I don't have to.

Anyone ever done/tried this? Just wondering if it's possible.

Appreciated as always!

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2010 you can have specific content types document libraries that use document templates, which made me think yes its possible as in the link you have given they is a option to select your own file template for Excel documents. I never done it within a SharePoint workflow but I am pretty sure you can create a document library just for excel documents, save it as a template and then upload it where they are specifying "Upload a new document template". It should work.

Other then that I find this link on MSDN which got what you exactly need.

[SharePoint 2010: Creating Excel 2010 Documents with Custom SharePoint Workflows](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2010-Creating-a11f6e68)

Here's a [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/set-a-file-template-for-a-document-or-form-library-HA102771909.aspx) to create a custom document library with a custom content type too.

Comment: thanks I appreciate the answer and all the resources, however I am a bit confused. Can I use and Excel template to create an xml file? I need to create a xml file and file that file with content from list item (like I would with the MS Word approach, but just raw xml).